# Powershell changes are not affected in Web UI

Tags: 2013, powershell, script

Not the first time I noticed that sometimes PowerShell changes are not seen in UI. By example this script:

```
# change web description example
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$myWeb = Get-SPWeb http://myserver/myweb
$myWeb.Description = "Some test description"
$myWeb.Update()
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```

seems to be ok, it works, and when I check it in powershell

```
$myWeb = Get-SPWeb http://myserver/myweb
$myWeb.Description
```

it shows new description. But in web interface

```
http://myserver/myweb/_layouts/15/prjsetng.aspx
```

I still do not see it

What I need to do to make it right

Using Win 2012 R2, SP2013, Powershell ISE.

Comment: Do you have any language packs installed on the server?

Comment: Yes, there is "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2013 1049 Lang Pack". But I think it was included in base ISO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have language packs installed, then we should use `DescriptionResource` for setting the values

```
$myWeb.DescriptionResource.SetValueForUICulture($myWeb.UICulture, "Some test description")
```